# текст в ячейке dataGridView занимает только одну линию

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, datagridview

у меня есть C# .NET Framework приложение, которое работает с JSON файлами. В json файле у меня хранится довольно длинный отрезок текста, но когда я вывожу его в dataGridView с помощью этого кода:

```
_problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = userProblems["text"];
```

То мой текст занимает только одну линию в ячейке dataGridView:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите я его полностью просто так увидеть не могу. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то сделать так что-бы текст занимал все пространство ячейки? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно через wrap попробовать. Здесь посмотри https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847993/how-to-set-the-datagridviewcell-to-automatically-word-wrap

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена. Вот что я сделал:

1. Зашел в Edit Columns моего dataGridView
2. Там выбрал нужную мне колонку
3. Затем нашел пункт AutoSizeMode и изменил его на Fill. Можно также поменять на AllCells, тоже будет работать.